# duplicating rows of data and then adding a series of dates in a new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataset in the below format however the data set is a lot bigger:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'From': ['RU','USA','ME'],
               'To': ['JK', 'JK', 'JK'],
               'Distance':[ 40000,30000,20000],
               'Days': [8,6,4]})
```

I want to add a date range to each location:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='01/02/2020', freq='MS', periods=3)
```

The end result should look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/02/2020' , '01/03/2020', '01/04/2020','01/02/2020' , '01/03/2020', '01/04/2020','01/02/2020' , '01/03/2020', '01/04/2020'],
               'From': ['RU', 'RU', 'RU','USA', 'USA', 'USA','ME', 'ME', 'ME'],
               'To': ['JK', 'JK', 'JK','JK', 'JK', 'JK','JK', 'JK', 'JK'],
               'Distance':[ 40000, 40000, 40000,30000, 30000, 30000,20000, 20000, 20000],
               'Days': [8,8,8,6,6,6,4,4,4]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df1["Date"]=pd.Series({df1.index[0]: date_rng.to_list()})
df1["Date"]=df1["Date"].ffill()
df1=df1.explode("Date")
```

Output:

```py
  From  To  Distance  Days       Date
0   RU  JK     40000     8 2020-02-01
0   RU  JK     40000     8 2020-03-01
0   RU  JK     40000     8 2020-04-01
1  USA  JK     30000     6 2020-02-01
1  USA  JK     30000     6 2020-03-01
1  USA  JK     30000     6 2020-04-01
2   ME  JK     20000     4 2020-02-01
2   ME  JK     20000     4 2020-03-01
2   ME  JK     20000     4 2020-04-01
```

Ref:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: With my real dataset it gives me the following error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: ```pip3 install --upgrade pandas``` (or ```pip```) it's new in version 0.25.0

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was as simple as that.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will do what you need:

```
l = []
for d in date_rng:
    df1['Date'] = d
    l.append(df1.copy())

pd.concat(l)
```

Comment: Depending on the size of data frame, and length of ```date_rng``` this might get really slow. ```pandas.DataFrame.explode(...)``` should provide better performance overall.